# Jquery: How to count endless until 10 on mouseenter event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script to count until 10 and show 0.

But how to count **endless** from 0 to 10 on mouseenter event and show 0 on mouseleave event?

```
$('.div').mouseenter(function() {
  var cnt = 0;
  var counter = setInterval(function() {
    if (cnt < 10) {
      $('.count').html(cnt);
      cnt++;
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(counter);
      $('.count').html("0");
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you need. How can you count endless to 10?

Comment: explanation definitely needs clarification.

Comment: Some kind of homework I guess!

Comment: If your selector is referring to element divs it should be simply `'div'`; the dot selector is for classnames, so `'.div'` matches elements with the classname `div`, which seems like a strange classname...

Comment: I've character on my page that count from 0 to 10 on mouseenter event, but i need loop function to count from 0 to 10 endless. Take a look how i use at the moment http://jsfiddle.net/e8wEp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, this might be what you want:

```
var counter;
$('.count-wrap').mouseenter(function() {
    var cnt = 0; counter = window.setInterval(function() {
        $('.count').html(cnt);
        cnt = (cnt+1)%11;
    }, 100);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    window.clearInterval(counter);
    $('.count').html("0");
});
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer! You can chain the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` function calls together to reduce the work done to select the element: `$(element).mouseenter(/**/).mouseleave(/**/);`

Comment: You're right, forgot about that. :)

Comment: You unterstand my question correctly, thanks. But mouseleave event don't work and when you touch again counter is accelerated. Take a loot at http://jsfiddle.net/NnC8c/

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I edited my answer.

Comment: You are the best rescuer around the world :) Thanks!